# Duplicate DOM id's and jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it ok to have multiple dom elements with the same id on a page, if those elements are only ever contained in various, identical jQuery UI dialogs?  For example:

```
    <div id="tabInfo" class="tabDiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-info">Book Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-reviews">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-subjects">Related Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-alsoByAuthor">Also by Author</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-info">
        ...
```

The `tabInfo` div is turned into a tab control, and inserted into a dialog.  But I can have multiple dialogs open at once, all drawing from this code.  As a result, I could have multiple divs on my page with the id `tabInfo`, `tabs-info`, `tabs-reviews`, etc.

This all seems to work fine.  My question is, is jQuery UI coded to handle this situation, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Multiple ids are not valid HTML, people who use non-valid HTML pay dearly. The best way to fix this issue is use classes instead of ids.

Comment: @Raynos - how ominous :)

Comment: There should never be multiple IDs. If you did that to work with the DOM (use 'names') and if you did that for the CSS (use 'classes')

Comment: @ajax333221 - I did that to work with jQuery tabs.  Each tab element expects an li with an `a` inside, with an intra page link to the id of the div whose content it represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Id's need to be 100% unique to the page, that is the nature of Id's. If you need multiples then use a class instead of an Id or generate your ids dynamically like `tabInfo_1`, `tabInfo_2` etc.

I dont know that having non-unique Id's would break your code, but it shouldnt be a question in the first place because according to the standard they need to be unique.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id

Comment: +1 true; but jQuery won't care.  It'll just grab the first one it sees.

Comment: Thats true enough Jeremy, but id still advocate the dynamic id's :-) No need to abuse loopholes :-)

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs the DOM won't care either, it will just grab the first element it finds by id. Still one should never do this

Comment: Well my top `tabInfo` can easily be a class, but is there an easy way to get all those tab divs—tabs-info, tab-sreviews—to use class ids instead of ids?  I don't think you can say `<a href=".tabs-info"` and I'd prefer to not throw a global static counter into my code just for this

Comment: @Raynos - any advice as to my comment above?

Comment: @AdamRackis You can't. If you want hrefs to fragment identifiers then you need ids. This is fixed by making them all unique. This can be done by prefixing it with junk, but that's ugly. The easier solution is only having one tab control in the DOM tree at any one time. But that's also ugly because `url/#id` is overloaded depending on "document state", i.e. which tab control is in the document

Comment: @Raynos - ok, thank you.  I'll look at making the ids unique.

Comment: FTR, no arguments from me, I was just pointing out that while it's not legal, it won't blow up... which is kinda worse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend it, for various reasons that you probably know, but jQuery can handle a selector for an ID returning multiple values. It will probably work fine, for now, but if you decide to update at a later point to a version of jQuery which doesn't support this functionality you'll be SOL.

Standards exist for a reason, and when you're working with the DOM you're working with incomplete implementations of standards, so I would recommend finding another way.

Comment: No it can't. `jQuery("#id").length === 1`. It does not find multiple elements by the same id.